# Why does my application give SerializationException although I have no serialized classes?

Tags: .net, serialization, biztalk

I have created an application deployment tool for BizTalk, and it references uses Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM apis to start, stop and manage a BizTalk application. Now when I run the tool, it gives following exception-

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer' in Assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
```

None of my classes are defined to be serializable. And the tool is created in WPF.

Any idea how I might resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because BtsCatalogExplorer is not marked as serializable.  Yes, that's the obvious answer.

Are you running this within BizTalk, in an Orchestration?  To run within BizTalk, a class must be Serializable or run within an Atomic Scope.

Comment: No I am not running it from within an Orchestration. It's meant to be a standalone app to deploy my BizTalk application, after the solution is built using MSBuild. I can deploy just fine using BTSTask commands, but for tasks like- to check if the app already exist, to start or stop the application- I need to use Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM

Comment: Found the reason though. I was creating the instance of BtsCatalogExplorer through reflection, using connection string instead solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at BTDF for BizTalk deployment. It's an open source and meet all the need of BizTalk Deployment http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com